# How to modify finite differences method for function which expects symmetric matrix as argument

Tags: derivatives, symmetric-matrices, finite-differences

I have some function $f(X): R^{3\times 3} -> R$ which designed to be used with symmetric matrix $X$ as argument. It's possible to evaluate it on any $X$ but it have no meaning for my problem. In order to take a simple derivative of this function i need to use fact that $X$ is symmetric. Also, if i'm not mistaken i should modify my "gradient matrix" $A$ (from $df = A : dX$) to be $A = (A + A^T) - A \circ I$. (Please, let me know if i get it wrong).

This derivative is not simple, so I want to check that everythink is ok by taking numerical derivative of my function by finite differences method. But finite differences has no clue that my argument should be symmetric, so i cannot use vanila algorithm.

How should i modify finite differences for my function?

Comment: What does it mean for a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be symmetric? Or is it $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$?

Comment: @Ian Oh, my fault, of course i mean matrix 3x3, i will edit post. Thank you!

Comment: You can just think of it as a function of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^9$, or exploit the symmetry to only deal with a function of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^6$. The rest is just bookkeeping.

Comment: @Ian yeah reparametrization by $R^6$ is a way to go, also, it's possible to use $g(Y) = f(Y + Y^T)$ trick to avoid such problem. I just wondering is there any tool to deal with such problem directly. 
I'm not sure that i get idea of $R^9$. I can use flattened argument, but i'm not sure that this trick will remove dependencies of symmetric elements. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Thinking of it in $\mathbb{R}^9$ would result in a gradient that acts on forbidden directions, which is not inherently a problem but is probably less convenient for your needs than thinking of it in terms of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: @Ian thank you for explanation!